# Why am I segfaulting?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fopen

I'm very new to C, I am attempting to read the contents of one file character by character and output them to the stream. But even with my fopen() command commented out I receive segfault (core dumped).

I must run a command: ./a.out < testWords.in > myOut.txt to execute my file properly.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
void main(char *fileName[]) 
{
  printf("filename is %s.\n",fileName[0]);
  //Get file based on a string inputed
  FILE *fp=fopen(fileName[0],"r"); //Fetches our file as read only
  char ch;
  int lineCount = 0;
  int wordCount = 0;
  int charCount = 0;

  //Failed to find/open file. NULL character.
  if (fp == 0) printf("Woops! Couldn't open file!\n");

  //While not at end of file, grab next char.
  else while( (ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF) 
    {
      if (ch == '\n') //on newline
      {
    //Prints (charCount,wordCount)\n lineCount:
    printf("(%d,%d)%c%d:",charCount,wordCount,ch,lineCount);
    charCount = 0;
    lineCount += 1;
      }
      else printf("%c",ch); //mirrors char.
    }
  fclose(fp); //Closes file (gotta be tidy!)

}
```

Comment: because you're invoking undefined behavior. Look at your `main()` params. you seem to be missing something pretty important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just invent a way to call `main`. You need to use one of the standard ways, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Missing filename\n");
        return -1;
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    // ...
}
```

And note that `argv[0]` contains the program name (if available; if not it contains an empty string).

Your program segfaulted because you received the `int argc` argument into your `char *filename[]` parameter. If you ran the program with a single command line parameter, the value passed in as the first argument would have been 2, which is not a valid pointer value. The expression `filename[0]` dereferences that address and causes a segfault.

Comment: This got rid of my segfault, but with my command: " ./a.out < testWords.in > myOut.txt  " I receive the error for Missing Filename. Why?

Comment: Because you haven't provided any command line arguments. Instead, you've redirected stdin and stdout. If that's what you want, then get rid of all the `FILE` stuff and just read from stdin and write to stdout (with, for example, `fgets` or `scanf`, and `printf`).

Answer (score 0):

Any time you get a segfault in C, you should *smell* a bad pointer or address in an argument list.  In this particular case., the signature of main is **always** `int main(int argc, char** argv)`.  Yours isn't.

What you want is

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  ...
  FILE * fp = fopen(argv[1]); // Quiz: why argv[1]? What's argv[0]?
```

You're getting away with it in the compiler because, basically, luck.

I also notice in your example call, there's actually *no* argument in the argument list, because you're using redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

And use argv[1] as fileName.

Main function must receive always that two parameters.